# How to perform a click() using Google Chrome's Console? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, click, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to make a Javascript code that automates a button click on a webpage, so I am trying to figure out the code with Google Chrome's Console. This is the button:

`<a href="#" class="link">Get Link</a>`

I thought I could simply write this:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('link');
button.click()
```

But this message appears:

`"Uncaught TypeError: button.click is not a function at <anonymous>:2:8"`

Any solution? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a live [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not a single element.

> *elements* is a live [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of found elements.

So if you want to use `getElementsByClassName`, you need to get the first item from the iterable like this:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('link');
button[0].click()
```

If you want to get a single element, use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). This will return the first found element.

```
var button = document.querySelector('.link');
button.click()
```

Comment: Using:
``` 
var button = document.querySelector('.link');
button.click() 
``` 
makes this error message appear: 
` "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null at <anonymous>:2:8"

Comment: are you executing the selector before the element? you need to execute it after the element or on [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Comment: I publish an answer below with a screenshot of what I wrote

Comment: You probably want `document.querySelector('.btn.btn-success.btn-lg.get-link')` a `querySelector` is written the same way a css selector is written.

Answer (score -2):

[This is a screenshot of the line I wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CohEx.png)

Is it correct?